# Is update required after recreating or renewing provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an application which is published in App Store. I have activated the push notifications and i think i need to renew or recreate the provisioning profile which is related to this application.

Do i need to release an update for the application after this?

Comment: Don't you need to add code to your app to send the push token to the server and to do something with the notification?

Comment: I have added the required code parts to the app already but have forgotten to activate the push notification from the member center accidently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to recreate the provisioning profile and build your app with the new profile. Otherwise your app won't have the aps entitlement,  which allows it to receive push notifications.

So yes, you'll need to release an update. When you submitted your app to app store,  didn't you get a warning that your app contains push notifications code but lacks the aps entitlement?  I've seen several questions in SO that mentioned getting such warning in similar circumstances.